# How to fill gap in GEE (JavaScript)

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, land-surface-temperature, gap

I am trying to creat LST maps for given dates. But the images have gap (stripes) for months Jan to Apr in 2011 and 2016. The following is the link of my code in GEE (JavaScript):

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0562b2714f6efdc17bf2e0a7829e2055